# ADL lookup inside a class (template) member function body

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, argument-dependent-lookup, class-members

```
struct B {};
struct C : B {};
void f(B){} // worse match than A::f<C>

struct A {
    template<class T>
    void f(T v) {
        f(v); // #1
    }
};

int main()
{
    A{}.f(C{});
}
```

Activating ADL lookup in line `#1` is as simple as

```
{
    using ::f;
    f(v);
}
```

I think the rule that makes the code fail without the `using` directive is:

> [**[basic.lookup.argdep]/3**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lookup#argdep-3) Let X be the lookup set produced by unqualified lookup and let Y be
>   the lookup set produced by argument dependent lookup (defined as
>   follows). If X contains
>
> - (3.1) a declaration of a class member, or
> - (3.2) a block-scope function declaration that is not a using-declaration, or
> - (3.3) a declaration that is neither a function nor a function template
>
> then Y is empty. [...]

So, since a call to `f` found by non-ADL lookup will find `A::f`, which is a class member, overloads found by ADL-lookup are discarded.

Which C++ rule allows to ignore the restriction in 3.1 with the `using` declaration, to make the above code compile?

I think I'm completely misunderstanding the context where the rule *[basic.lookup.argdep]/3* must be applied, or maybe I have a bigger and hidden hole in my understanding of the name lookup process.

Comment: Well, you already have an MCVE, but I really think you could have reduced your code considerably more...

Comment: @Rakete1111 I think that is not so long considering that I need, (A) A member function, (B) A user namespace with a user defined class, (C) At least two overloads of a same operator, (D) A main function.

Comment: It's maybe not long, but it has a lot of things that are not necessary (like inheriting from a reference wrapper, `ostreamable_with`, ...) IMO.

Comment: Mind if I reduce the code for you?

Comment: @Columbo Ok but add some kind of comment to say that the "code has been adapted to that specific question", or send me a coliru or any kind of online compiler/pastebin link to see the code first and I do the changes. As wish.

Comment: @Peregring-lk See if you like it, otherwise revert-

Answer (score 5):

[First paragraph](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.unqual#1) on unqualified name lookup:

> In all the cases listed in [basic.lookup.unqual], the scopes are
>   searched for a declaration in the order listed in each of the
>   respective categories; name lookup ends as soon as a declaration is
>   found for the name.

[In particular](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.unqual#8),

> For the members of a class `X`, a name used in a member function body […], following
>   the member's *declarator-id*, shall be declared in one of the
>   following ways:
>
> - before its use in the block in which it is used or in an enclosing
>     block ([[stmt.block]](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.block)), or
> - shall be a member of class `X` or be a member
>     of a base class of `X` ([[class.member.lookup]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.member.lookup)), or ...

A local (re)declaration of a name is prioritised and shadows all extrinsic declarations.

Comment: Ahhh!! and then ADL lookup will found the function member again and added to the overloaded set if the number of parameters match, isn't?

Comment: @Peregring-lk Yes, the `user::operator<<` will be found via `ref`'s template argument's associated namespace.

Comment: The `user::operator<<` is not a member function. Besides, what is `ref`? And consider the operator syntax too: `using std::operator<<; *this << v;`.